# how to add phone number field in registeration page of mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i want to add phone number field on default registration page of MVC5 Web Application.
and when a user register with given info the user data store in default database of AspNetUsers table in PhoneNumber column.

here is my code for register View.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Number, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Number, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
    </div>
</div>
```

}

and here is code for register view model.

```
 public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your must provide a PhoneNumber")]

    [Phone]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

String number is also used in Manage.so i use the same name.but when a user register its phone number is not showing on database table.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is include the phone number in the ApplicationUser like this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, PhoneNumber = model.Phone };
```

You can find that object in the

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, PhoneNumber = model.Phone };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

function in the AccountController.cs in a fresh MVC5 project. You can check the AspNetUsers table to see where it went.

It is probably wiser to not store your user data in that table, but create a seperate table for things like phone numbers, etc. That way you can keep your AccountController uncluttered and lean.

For the record, I just did a 'Create new project > MVC' in my VS2012. Nothing was changed from the default settings the new project came with except adding the Phone property to the model and an input field to the view, just like you did.